# Ubuntu bash toolbar not visible

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I've disabled the toolbar of my console in bash. Apparently there is not short-cut key (hat I know off) to switch the toolbar's visibility. Is there an easy way to get my toolbar back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard terminal (`gnome-terminal`), right click into the terminal window and check the *Show Menubar* checkbox.

Comment: Duh! This is the first time I've right-clicked in the window it self. Somehow I always perceived it as text and not being capable of showing context dialogs, dunno why... Thanks!